# Connection drops after about 5 seconds and is real slow with a Centrino 1030 wireless card

Tags: 11.10, connection, intel-wireless

I have a Dell XPS 15 with dual boot windows 7 ultimate and Ubuntu 11.10 and the wireless connection is really bad on Ubuntu, I have 2-5mbps in Ubuntu and keep losing the connection for 5sec, but in windows I have 20mbps and its good and fast...

I have Intel Centrino wireless-N 1030

I have tried to [turn Power Management to off](https://askubuntu.com/a/92517/235) and it got up to 7-10mbps so that helped now but i still keep losing the internet connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try as suggested here; someone with the same wifi card has this problem and solved it switching off the power mode to the wifi:

> ```
> iwconfig wlan0 | grep "Power Management" Power Management:off
> ```
>
> If it’s set to “on” then there become my performance problems. To
>   change it on runtime you just have to do :
>
> ```
> sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
> ```
>
> If you, like me, want to set it always off then you can for example
>   modify the script `/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/wireless` . I simply set
>   this on line 39 (it's iwlagn) : `iwconfig_batt="power off"`

http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1845983.html

Comment: I tried all those information stuff that he did but when i did 'uname -mr' i got '3.0.0-14-generic-pae i686' instead of '2.6.38-11-generic x86_64' what he's getting.
And i tried to set it to off and rebooted and didn't help :(

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with a centrino wlan chip, until I changed the settings for the interrupt in the bios. Maybe it doesn't solve your problem, but you could give it a try.