# Wireless dropping with an Intel Centrino Wireless-N 1030

Tags: wireless, 12.04, intel-wireless

a friend of mine has the same problem like many other users with Ubuntu Precise.
With Ubuntu 12.04 wireless is dropping sometimes. He has to reconnect to the wifi SSID.

This is the relevant output of such a drop: http://fixee.org/paste/8hwpt89/
Would be nice to get help if someone knows why this occurs.

**Info**
The network hardware is the following: http://fixee.org/paste/tu9x728/

*I post this as links to keep the question short and clean*

**Update 2nd of May**
Here you have more `dmesg` informations: http://fixee.org/paste/tkv95th/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connection drops after about 5 seconds and is real slow with a Centrino 1030 wireless card](http://askubuntu.com/questions/92512/connection-drops-after-about-5-seconds-and-is-real-slow-with-a-centrino-1030-wir)

Comment: If that solution doesn't do it for you, please either request to reopen saying so.

Comment: OP has flagged for this to remain open since the above link has not resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by changing the security method of your router from WEP to WPA/WPA2. I have the same wireless hardware and had this issue but after changing the security the wireless connection worked fine for me. (Yes this solution aaplies to you if you are using WEP security)

I got idea of changing the security method from this link - [Wireless with WEP extremely slow on an Acer Timeline 4810T with a Centrino Wireless-N 1000](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81156/wireless-with-wep-extremely-slow-on-an-acer-timeline-4810t-with-a-centrino-wirel)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1971571

Faça download do driver adequado em http://intellinuxwireless.org/?n=downloads, descompacte-o e copie para a pasta /lib/firmware

Google translate from Portuguese:

Download the appropriate driver in http://intellinuxwireless.org/?n=downloads, unzip it and copy it to the folder /lib/firmware

Comment: Ratificando: o procedimento acima reduziu a frequência do problema, porém não solucionou.
O que realmente funcionou foi alterar a segurança do roteador de WEP para WAP.

Comment: Or in translation: Confirming: the above procedure reduced the frequency of the problem but not solved. What really worked was to change the router security from WEP to WPA.